# Django on godaddy - 500 internal server error OR Forbidden 403

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a deluxe Linux hosting account on Godaddy and from the past 3 days I've been trying to host a Django website.

I followed these tutorials:

http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2012/06/setup-django-1-4-on-godaddy-linux-economy-host/

[Installing a django site on GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658427/installing-a-django-site-on-godaddy)

http://blurback.com/post/563604002/running-django-on-godaddy-sigh

But I'm getting this:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache Server at www.gccfishing.com Port 80

I think the problem is with the python path which is written at the first line in files: `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7`, because when I try to execute a file in SSH I get this error:

`-bash: ./test.py: /usr/local/bin/python2.7^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.`

where test.py is a sample test file and it's chmoded.

This is my folder configuration on godaddy:

```
home
    content
        88
            10907688
                .pip
                data
                error_logs
                html
                lib
                scctmp
                tmp
```

In `html` I'm placing files according to the above mentioned tutorials which are either dispatch.py or .cgi files.

In `lib` I have the following:

```
venv 
    bin 
        gccFishing (this is the Django project)
        MySQLdb
        python ( file type: File)
        python2.7 ( file type: 7 File)
        django-admin.py
        acitvate_this.py
    include
        shortcut folder of python2.7
    lib
        python2.7
            shortcuts to all python libraries
            site-packages(this is where I downloaded Django)
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Which files does Apache execute first?

Should I use dispatch.py or dispatch.cgi?

Any help/comments will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

was made in windows, then uploaded.

```
-bash: ./test.py: /usr/local/bin/python2.7^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

It contains the ^M, which is a windows newline character. Try editing in VIM on the server and you will see them. Convert to UNIX text file.

Be sure when you edit text files on windows that you save them in UNIX format if you are uploading to a linux server.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Thank you.