# Forbidden Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: python, django

I get this error when i try to access the system using http://membersite.haoyetu.com/.this the link to the server `http://membersite.haoyetu.com/`
this my manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "membersite.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Did you search for similar questions? Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17711277/3901060 ? If that doesn't help, you will need to update your question with more useful information. The full traceback would be a good start.

Comment: @FamousJameous i followed the question but i did get the solution so i thought may if i ask i will get a better answer that will help me solve my problem. i have been stack on that problem for three good days this being the fourth.i have followed this  stackoverflow.com/q/17711277/3901060 but it did help to solve my problem.